# save dynamic image from element to disk

Tags: watir

Method save not implemented yet in watir-webdriver, but exist in watir-classic. Are there any other methods to preserve the dynamic images? When I`m try download image by url image changing. Is it possible to get an image from the cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save a screenshot, if that would help: http://watirwebdriver.com/screenshots/

Getting an image from the cache should be doable from Ruby, but it is not implemented in Watir.